# android setEnabled but unchange text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have some edit text fields which I would like to make un-editable at certain times. I have used the setEnabled method but that also grays out the text. Is there a way to toggle whether the field can be edited but not change the appearance of the text? It has been a little while since I last messed with Android but I think I used to be able to use setEditable which did exactly what I am looking for.

I have tried to use the android:focusable="false" but I am still able to edit the field, unless that is only the behavior of the emulator I don't think that will work.

Comment: probably that gray-out will be in the background drawable, with the selector `enabled="false"`, you can assign a custom background -ie.black- and see if it grays out. If it doesn't, create a nice drawable with the underline, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable input for an EditText without any visible indication by setting it's input type to `InputType.TYPE_NULL`. An example would look like:

```
import android.text.InputType;
. . .
myEditText..setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Note that this behavior doesn't exactly jive with what the [reference docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NULL) seem to be saying and that there doesn't appear to be an XML equivalent.

Comment: Thank, works great for my standard edit texts and its easy to re-enable using InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER. I also have a edit text but it has a touch listener date picker associated with it. Do you know of way to give it a similar behavior because setInputType does not work for it?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with those, but perhaps you can set the min and max dates to the current date to keep the user from being able to change the date.